# Firebase security: uid and facebook.id

Tags: firebase, facebook-authentication, firebase-security

So I am trying to build security shield to my App. My database structure of users is in the first line, and below I have my initial security rules:

```
/users/[facebook id of user]/[data]


{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user": {
        ".read": "auth.uid === $user",
        ".write": "auth.uid === $user"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question is: can I format the security rule, so that **auth.id**
 is compared to the string: **"facebook:" + $user**?

Or should I change all my database to use original **auth.uid as a userID**? So far I have been using facebook.id as a userID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`auth.uid` is not equivalent to `"facebook:" + facebook.id` so no, you can't simply use that. You'll need to use `auth.uid` if you want to uniquely identify your users in security rules.

If you are in production, as an intermediate step to rewriting all your user ids, you could add the auth.uid as a field and reference that:

```
".write": "data.child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
```

But I would not try to use that as a permanent solution as you'll run into more issues as you progress.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that would be a must, so I've already changed all of my database structure to userID as auth.uid! Have a great day!